# Automatically Call Function Based on Body Class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a basic site with ~6 pages and I have my javascript structure setup like the following:

```
var MYSITE = {};

// this gets the class on the body in the HTML
MYSITE.getPage = function(){
   var _bodyClass = $('body').attr('class').split(/\s/),
       curPage    = _bodyClass[ 0 ];
   return curPage;
};

MYSITE.Common = (function(){
    var init = function(){
       // do global stuff
    };       

    return {
       init: init 
    }
})();

MYSITE.Home = (function(){
   var init = function(){
       // do homepage specific stuff
   };
   return {
       init: init
   }
})();

MYSITE.About = (function(){
   var init = function(){
       // do about page specific stuff
   };
   return {
       init: init
   }
})();

// etc

// DOM Ready
$(function() {
    MYSITE.Common.init();

    if( MYSITE.getPage() === 'home' ) {
        MYSITE.Home.init();
    }

    if( MYSITE.getPage() === 'about' ) {
        MYSITE.About.init();
    }

    // etc
});
```

I'd like to call those specific functions based on the `body` class in my HTML. I've tried this so far and it works, but everytime I add a page I have to update my JS.

How can I automatically fire the correct module function based on the `body` class in my HTML?

Comment: What about adding a second `<script>` tag before you load the main script that sets a variable to key off of instead of going with the body tag?  If that's not an option, what about a `data` attribute in the body tag? Read about it here: [data-](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes)

Comment: `MYSITE[MYSITE.getPage()].init()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the bodys class to reference the property name in the object, just capitalize the first letter first.

```
$(function() {
    MYSITE.Common.init();

    var site = MYSITE.getPage();

    site = site.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + site.slice(1); // capitalize first

    MYSITE[site].init();
});
```